# Navigation issue when resuming after pressing windows button - WP8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

**WP8.1 Silverlight App**

I have set up a urimapper to launch different pages according to different conditions. Function SetUriMapper is called in App constructor

**App.xaml**

```
<UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
    <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/RootPage.xaml" />
</UriMapper:UriMapper>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    public App()
    {
        // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Standard Silverlight initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();

       // Database functions

        SetupUriMapper();
   }

    void SetupUriMapper()
    {
        // Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame
        UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
        RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;


       if (condition)
       {
           mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/Walkthrough.xaml",       UriKind.Relative);
       }
       else if (condition2)
       {
           mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/ResetPasswordPrompt.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
       }
       else 
           mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
     }


    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
            // reading data from database
            CycleManager cycMan = CycleManager.Instance;

            using (DBManager dbMan = new DBManager())
            {
                dbMan.OpenConnection();
                dbMan.ReadSettingsData(cycMan.ActiveAccount);
            }
    }
```

Now the user is in page B. And presses home button. Then goes to the app list and select the app again. `Application_Activated` is called and is navigated to page B. But within a second it navigates back to MainPage.

But if the user presses the back button to resume, it navigates to Page B and stays there.

Behavior is strange, Any clues?

Comment: What is `condition`? What about `condition3`? Where is the code located in App.xaml.cs? More information would be helpful. There's a difference between pressing the back button and launching the app from the app list.

Comment: @qxwevr I have updated the code. SetupUriMapper is used to set the mappings. And this function is called in the App constructor.
Conditions are these, if the app is installed first time, a walkthrough, is shown. If a password is set, password page is shown. Else the default mainpage is shown

Comment: Can you put code for activated event handler?

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Apart from reading data from DB, I'm not doing anything in the activated event handler.

Comment: which app this is ? silverligt or RT or universal ?

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia WP8.1 Silverlight

Comment: Can you try putting your mapper methods to activated event instead of constructor? Put it after your database operations.

Comment: But if I put the mapper methods, in the activated event, the app wont resume where it left right? It will re-map and then open in MainPage right?

Comment: I understood that you want app to resume based on your conditions.

Comment: For startup yes, it will start up based on the conditions, but if the app is in some page and then deactivated, it should ideally come back to the same page where it left off. So for instance if page b is where I left, i need to come back to page b if i press back or the app icon for entering app.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is because of the fast app resume feature WP8.

You need to set `ActivationPolicy` as well as events for resetting navigation. This link gives you details of how to resume the app back to where you left off.

[Ed Glogowski's Blog](http://edglogowski.azurewebsites.net/?p=9441)